# GetThreadInformation() fails

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

Pretty simple thing, I want to use [`GetThreadInformation()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-getthreadinformation) from the windows API. Usage seems pretty simple from its documentation, but it fails. Code:

```
THREAD_POWER_THROTTLING_STATE state{};
const bool return_value = GetThreadInformation(
   GetCurrentThread(),
   ThreadPowerThrottling,
   &state,
   sizeof(THREAD_POWER_THROTTLING_STATE)
);
```

Return value is always false, which indicates an error. `GetLastError()` indicates a wrong parameter. The documentation does talk about that the thread needs to have the proper rights. But `GetCurrentThread()` documentation clearly states that it returns a handle with `THREAD_ALL_ACCESS` rights. So what's wrong? This is on Win10.

Comment: `ThreadPowerThrottling` not supported. only `ThreadMemoryPriority`, `ThreadAbsoluteCpuPriority` and `ThreadDynamicCodePolicy`

Comment: @RbMm could you link a source? The function documentation states: "The only supported values are ThreadMemoryPriority and ThreadPowerThrottling"

Comment: documentation is wrong. `ThreadPowerThrottling` is only valid for `SetThreadInformation`. and for `GetThreadInformation` also `ThreadAbsoluteCpuPriority` is valid. simply look code under debugger

Comment: uhm okay, not sure what to look at there. Windows API is a black box, debugger doesn't show much.

Comment: no, winapi is not black box for me. here all is very easy visible

Comment: also why you initially decide that error somehow related to handle access rights ? you not got error access denied. you got error invalid parameter. need how minimum analyze error value

Comment: I was eliminating possible errors to narrow down the problem. I'm still confused as to how the windows source code is "very easy visible"

Comment: yes, very easy all visible under debugger. how minimum for me. and error `ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER` not related to handle access rigths.

Comment: Win11 required, afaict.  And initialize state properly: THREAD_POWER_THROTTLING_STATE state { THREAD_POWER_THROTTLING_CURRENT_VERSION };

Comment: @RbMm "*simply look code under debugger*" - Do you mean reverse engineering?

Comment: @jtxkopt - yes.

Comment: `Win11`  nothing change here

Comment: *"how the windows source code is "very easy visible""* - It isn't. While you can request to get source code access, this user is talking about looking at the disassembly in a debugger. With symbols (that are publicly available) that's pretty close to the original C source code. Also, questioning the thread handle here is perfectly reasonable: The other 3 arguments come straight from the documentation, so clearly the thread handle would be an obvious candidate to consider. If this user is confusing to you, make sure you understand that they will not miss a chance to brag about their mad skills.

Comment: @IInspectable *the thread handle here is perfectly reasonable* - no. if thread handle will be not ok, will be another error (`STATUS_INVALID_HANDLE`, `STATUS_OBJECT_TYPE_MISMATCH`, `STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED` ). but error was `STATUS_INVALID_PARAMETER` .  this clear say that task not in handle. how you think - what sense in error code ? are it by self talk about something ? if not - what sense in error code at all, if complete ignore it value

Comment: I clearly stated in the question and my other reply that I can *rule out* the thread handle as a source of the problem. I mentioned it to prevent people suggesting that's where the error is. I don't understand why this comes up repeatedly. It's a completely reasonable context information.

Comment: By sheer coincidence, Raymond Chen wrote a blog article the other day: [The error code you get might not be the one you want](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20220119-00/?p=106176). The sub-heading is quite fitting: *"Some error codes are contractual, but most aren't."* I wonder where RbMm got the idea from, that the error codes returned by `GetThreadInformation` were of the contractual kind.

Comment: @IInspectable - yes, sometime error codes can be mixed up, but basically win32 errors, due not injective translation from *NTSTATUS*. the nt errors in most case relevant. also important is how complex function internal, how many different task (any of which can fail). in case this concrete api and thread handle - error can be only from [`ObReferenceObjectByHandle`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/wdm/nf-wdm-obreferenceobjectbyhandle). and error which this api can return well known (3 values) and for `STATUS_INVALID_PARAMETER` no place here

Answer (score 1):

the documetation of `GetThreadInformation` is wrong.

in part `ThreadInformationClass`: really supported values is: `ThreadMemoryPriority`,
`ThreadAbsoluteCpuPriority` and `ThreadDynamicCodePolicy`

the `ThreadPowerThrottling` is accepted only by `SetThreadInformation`.

so if pass `ThreadPowerThrottling` to `GetThreadInformation` we always got `ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER`

Comment: Documentation has been updated.